# How to return an image from own PHP page using other server url

Tags: php, image, url, return, todataurl

How can I make a PHP page that will return image from other server specified by url in variable, like this:

http://www.mypage.com/MyScript.php?src=http://www.otherpage.com/image.png

And after going to that page an image should apear.

It need to work for any other srcs too.

*(Why like this?
I want to try bypass the Security Error that apears using toDataUrl from canvas while using image not from the same domain, by using http://www.mypage.com/MyScript.php?src=http://www.otherpage.com/image.png as a image src used in canvas)*

Answer (score 0):

In `MyScript.php`, use `$_GET['src']` as the source of the image

```
<img src="<? echo $_GET['src']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['src']);
```

Comment: as long as the  fopen wrappers are enabled.

Comment: Using any img url shows error: Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /xxxx/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/Myscript.php on line 2 (line 2 is this code)

Comment: $_GET['src'] is empty, IMHO. Try print_r($_GET['src']) to check if it's empty or not. 
Or try echo file_get_contents('http://URL/TO/IMAGE.png') and test if file_get_contents works.